# SQL Server 2016 and SSDT: rebuild using devenv works in command line, not from TSQL xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, rebuild, devenv

I have a TSQL script to automate deployment of SSDT solutions into SQL Server SSIS Catalog. It uses several calls to command line to perform operations on files , which work fine (xp_cmdshell is enabled in configuration)

But the call to devenv to rebuild the .ispac file fails
with error message :

```
C:\Users\user1\DWH_home\01. SSIS Development\Log_BI\Log_BI\Log_BI.dtproj : error  : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly.
Please see the Output Window for details.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

command:

```
SET @cmd = @devenv + ' "' +  @DWH_home + @ispac_path  + '\'+ @project_name+'.sln" /Rebuild Development /Out '+ @current_log_file
print @cmd --debug
/* print output:
C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2017\SQL\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe "C:\Users\user1\DWH_home\01. SSIS Development\Log_BI\Log_BI\Log_BI.sln" /Rebuild Development /Out C:\Windows\Temp\SSIS_Current_build_log.txt
*/
DECLARE @result int;  
EXEC @result = xp_cmdshell @cmd;  

print @result 
--@result = 1
```

whereas the exact same command works OK in command line